# Get "CONN_REFUSED" and show according exception

Tags: php, exception, curl

I have the following function to see whether a stream is online or offline:

```
function remoteFileExists($url) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1000);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $ret = false;
    if ($result !== false) {
        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
        if ($statusCode == 200) {
            $ret = $url;   
        }
    }else{
         throw new Exception("img/webcam-offline.jpg");
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return $ret;
}
```

I now go through them with foreach()

```
try{
   $imgSrc = remoteFileExists($protocol.$device_protection.$ip.":".$port."/".$deviceStream);
}catch(Exception $e){
   $imgSrc = $e->getMessage();
}
```

This works perfectly fine. On one computer though, there is a "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" probably caused by a firewall. On this computer it does not show the offline image, is there any way to catch that as well?

Comment: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is a javascript/Chrome error isn't it? I'm not sure how this relates to the PHP you've posted?

Comment: yes, you are right, Chrome is the only one that actually shows an error, FF and IE simply do not load the stream and show the "missing image" icon. However, on the phone and several other computers it's fine. I don't want to fix the error itself, I only want to show a specific error message...